# How do I change button colours apart in a method?

Tags: java

I am trying to change 4 buttons from colour in a method, however the counter goes on even if I press one of the other buttons and I want that every button counts for it self and starts at 0 instead of going through where the other button has stopped.

```
int count = 0;

public void ColourChange(JButton jButtonColour1){
    //Changes the colours of the buttons, doesn't work good because it goes on counting for the other buttons too.

    //returns the counter to 0 after it gets to 10.
    if (count >= 10) {
        count = 0;
    }
    count++;

    //Makes sure it can be used at all the 4 buttons instead on just 1.
    JButton setColour = jButtonColour1, jButtonColour2, jButtonColour3, jButtonColour4;

    Color color;

        switch (count) {
            case 1:
                count = 1;
                setColour.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                break;
            case 2:
                count = 2;
                setColour.setBackground(Color.RED);
                break;
            case 3:
                count = 3;
                setColour.setBackground(Color.PINK);
                break;
            case 4:
                count = 4;
                setColour.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                break;
            case 5:
                count = 5;
                setColour.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                break;
            case 6:
                count = 6;
                setColour.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                break;
            case 7:
                count = 7;
                setColour.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
                break;
            case 8:
                count = 8;
                setColour.setBackground(Color.cyan);
                break;
            case 9:
                count = 9;
                setColour.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                break;
            case 10:
                count = 10;
                setColour.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "every counter"? There is only one counter variable in your code. If you want to have one for every button, you need to declare one for every button.

Comment: Do you want to change your buttons colours by clicking on them?

Comment: count = 1, count = 2, etc. in the switch is meaningless. Think why.

Comment: Do you want to change your buttons colours by clicking on them? – Russiancold 1 min ago

That is already working, but the problem is I want it to work for 4 buttons instead of just one, because now if I push the first button 4 times it will change the colour to green but if I push than on the second button the colour will start at blue instead of black and i want them al to start at the colour black

Comment: Also instead of your `switch` , you may create an array of `Color` objects e.g `Color[] colors = {Color.BLACK,Color.RED,etc...};` then call `setColour.setBackground(colors[count+1]);` .

Comment: Also, what are you trying to do with this line:     `JButton setColour = jButtonColour1, jButtonColour2, jButtonColour3, jButtonColour4;` ?  You cannot have a single variable point at 4 different other variables. The statement is equivalent to writing `JButton setColour = jButtonColour1; JButton jButtonColour2; JButton jButtonColour3; JButton jButtonColour4;` <- So you only have one assignment and 3 uninitialized new local variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
string buttonName="";
public int ColourChange(JButton jButtonColour1,int count){
//some codes
if(!(buttonName.equals(jButtonColour1.getText()))){
    buttonName=jButtonColour1.getText();//name or what are u using
    count = 0;
}
//some codes
switch (count) {
        case 1:
            count = 1;
            setColour.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            break;
        case 2:
            count = 2;
            setColour.setBackground(Color.RED);
            break;
        //............
    }
```